# Forcing maven to update local repository in jboss

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm experiencing this issue:
when updating a bundle in jboss (`osgi:update`) it is not retrieving the latest version from the remote maven repo but it is still using the cached version in `.m2` local repository. I know that there is a maven setting (in settings.xml) to force updatePolicy but is it possible to set it in jboss too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jboss maven configuration (`etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg`) is possible to set the updatePolicy:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.globalUpdatePolicy=always
```

even if the parameters seems not to be documented.